# My Git Repository is inside my User folder. Is this a performance concern?

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio-2013

Visual studio performance seems really slow on my machine, and I'm wondering if the problem is that my repo is inside my user folder.

I am using Windows 8.1.  We are using Git, and I configured my local repository to be inside C:\Users\Me\Source. The repo is 1.3 GB and contains 17,000 files.

I'm wondering if file operations inside a user folder is slower due to the security overhead.

Comment: Can you try with Git 2.4.6? (https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)

Comment: I am using Git version 2.48.05
I don't think the problem is with Git.  Git operations are fast.  It's visual studio that I am concerned about (loading projects, building, finding references, etc)

Comment: Ok, I thought it was Git the issue.

Comment: Git 2.48.05 doesn't exist. You're surely talking about gitextensions which come with git 1.95, so the remark of @VonC is still valid. The performance is surely not good due to your huge repository with perhaps a lot of binaries... And VS always take some times if changes are important between checkout even if it improves from version to version. 2015 is better...